# Get UUID of System and Update as Attribute in NiFi FlowFile

Tags: uuid, apache-nifi, apache-minifi

Is there a way to get the unique UUID of the system (Generated using dmidecode) in NiFi and set it as an Attribute to a FlowFile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah. It can be done using `ExecuteScript`. You can use `Groovy` and execute as simple as the following line to run a shell command.

```
"dmidecode".execute()
```

or to read the result generated:

```
def result = "dmidecode".execute().text
```

Then when you're done reading the required value/data from the result, you can use something like the following to assign the value as a FlowFile attribute

```
flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
def dmidecodeUuid = ... // your logic to read the UUID from dmidecode
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'dmidecode.uuid', dmidecodeUuid)
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

That's just a rough code which was quickly made. More details on ExecuteScript can be found at:

- https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html
- https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/75032/executescript-cookbook-part-1.html